# Smart undervoltage protection

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, protection, over-voltage-protection, undervoltage

what is the simplest way to regulate the min DC voltage in a circuit?

```
Desired performance:

Input > 5 VDC     Output = Switch power lane
Input = 5 VDC     Output = Input
Input < 5 VDC     Output = 0.
```

Current may be around 3A

The input voltage may be from 5v to 22v through USB type C connector. I decided to use module based on **MP1584EN** to step down voltage from >7V to 5V. But this module works unstable if an input voltage equals to output. And I can't imagine how to ignore this module if the input voltage equals 5V.

Thanks

**Update**
Ok, in case I will use default DC jack 5.5*2.1, and power adapter may be 5V, 9V, 12V, 24V. How to pass 5V directly, and input > 5V through **MP1584EN** module

New schematic 
[image]

Comment: You need a better problem statement, like with ranges and maybe hysteresis amounts . The voltage will never be exactly 5V for any length of time.

Comment: Just for future reference - Please note GND facing downwards and power nets upwards. Not sideways.

Comment: For example, I would like to use a power adapter from my phone or macbook. Both has typeC, but power adapter has output 5V, in case when macbook 20.2V

Comment: Do you realize that a USB-C power adapter will **only** supply more than 5 V **after** it has had some communication with the device connected to it. So if you build some gadget it will only receive 20 V over USB-C if it can **negotiate** that with the adapter. If it does not, it will only get 5 V. My point: without negotiation you can assume the USB-C to output 5 V and **never** 7 V or more.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I'm just started studying this stuff. Thanks, for an explanation. Imagine that I'll use standard 5.5*2.1 And input may be 5V, 9V, 12V, 24V? What I have to do in this case?

Comment: *I'm just started studying this stuff.* Then maybe USB-C is too complex for you. You might want to just use micro-USB so that you'll always just get 5 V. To get 9 V etc on USB-C you will need to read the USB-C specification and/or use a special chip to do the negotiation. Without a special USB-C chip, getting 9 V etc. out of a USB-C adapter is a challenge even for experienced engineers. Sure you'll want to do "everything" already now but that **will** end in tears and things not working. There is **no shame** in starting with simple projects and working your way up. We all did that.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie no, I'm trying to say, that input may be different, and how to pass directly 5V to a scheme, and in the input will be > 5V pass input through a step-down chip.

Comment: First, you would need special circuitry, Power Delivery Type-C IC such as [here](http://www.ti.com/interface/usb/type-c-and-power-delivery/products.html#p1694=PD%20controller) to be able to pass 66W through it. Without it, it will be a nightmare, seriously. [TPS65987D](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps65987d.pdf) could deliver up to 100W and that would be a suitable choice in your condition since it has integrated power switches. It's a 71 page datasheet, you could imagine how a Type-C connectors is so complex.